# “Table de matières” vs "Table des matières”?

Tags: grammaire

What is the difference between “Table de matières” and “Table des matières”?

Answer (score 3):

The version lacking an *s* is much rarer and dubious. After digging the few occurrences found by Google books, most of them seem to be just typos / mistakes.

Here are some occurrences of this dubious usage (the first one uses both forms):

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Similar phrases only use *des*:

- *Table **des** illustrations*
- *Table **des** chapitres*
- *Table **des** références*

*Des* makes sense because the table is referring to specific contents (Table of **the** contents/illustrations/chapters/references present in this book).

Compare:

- *Liste **de** noms*: A "random" list of names.
- *Liste **des** noms*: A list containing "the" names.

When the table contains generic content, *de* can be more frequent:

- *Table **de** logarithmes* (there is an infinite number of logarithms, the table can't be exhaustive.)

Answer (score 1):

**Table des matières**:

> La table des matières est placée à la fin de l’ouvrage. Elle détaille l’ensemble des divisions d’un document : parties, sous-parties, chapitres, paragraphes, etc.

**Sommaire**:

> Un sommaire est généralement placé au début de l’ouvrage. Il présente une liste synthétique des divisions du livre (par exemple, les grandes parties).

Table de matières sans `s` est très rare, voir utilisé uniquement lors d'exceptions en français.

Answer (score 0):

Table des matières means table of contents (in a book or similar document).
Table de matières is incorrect.

Comment: As much as *table of content* is ;-) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207086/table-of-contents-vs-table-of-content

Comment: Oh, right :-)..